# JavaScript template engines for mobile web applications

Tags: javascript, templates, jquery-mobile, jqtouch, template-engine

I'm building an application using jQTouch. I'd like to take advantage of one of the JavaScript template engines to avoid manual generation of HTML using data returned from JSON services.

Which engines are known to provide good mobile compatibility, and coexist well with jQTouch (and jQuery Mobile)?

Comment: Have same question. Bounty started.

Comment: please enumerate your priorities: Perfomance? Simplicity? Complexity? ...

Comment: @devundef Performance and compatibility with packaging tools.

Answer (score 4):

Compatibility is not a problem if your intention is to use the engine only in mobile browsers/wrappers (or modern desktop browsers). Moreover, the performance is essential for web-based mobile applications.

So you have a couple of options:

- *jQuery templates*

  - Pros: more or less well documented, widely used.
  - Cons: it is no longer being maintained by jQuery team, ie forever beta.
- *Clousure templates*:

  - Pros: rich construction blocks - ifs, foreach, etc. Can compile the same template for multiple targets (js, java ...)
  - Cons: you'll have to execute the compiler to compile the template even on development stage, that is, client side compilation is not available. For me, it's a pain. Although it's very powerful, seems like "a bazooka to kill a mosquito" if used only for web.
- *distal*

  - Never used, but it seems more like a "dynamic UI engine" like knockout or angularjs than a template engine.
- **mustache** (I pick this one).

  - It has a very simple (yet powerful) syntax - you can learn mustache in 15 minutes - and by not providing "complex blocks" it enforces you to create good models instead of fat and complex templates, with a bunch of ifs, whiles and foreachs.
  - There are engine versions for more than 10 languages, including javascript, .net, java, ruby...
  - Cons: The simplicity in a few cases becomes limiting
- **mustache + hogan**

  - Hogan is a compiler for the Mustache templating language written by the guys from twitter.
  - It is really fast
  - It can compile templates at runtime or pre-compile for packaging tools.
  - AMD compliant (has a plugin for requirejs)
  - Is in active development
  - Cons: poorly documented.

mustache: http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

hogan: https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js

Comment: Great answer! I have picked up mustache also.

Comment: Thank you @NikolayFominyh. I have used mustache+hogan and I haven't complaints. It's been very enjoyable.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Distal](http://code.google.com/p/distal) templates and it works on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I used jQuery templates for a large-scale jQuery Mobile single page app on ASP.NET MVC 3. Putting all the template files in a partial view worked quite well. Templates worked well on all browsers that jQuery Mobile supported including IE 6,7,8.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Answer (score 0):

How "big" is the application?  If you are primarily after templates you should give Google Closure Templates a try -

http://code.google.com/closure/templates/

Some concepts -

http://code.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts.html

Comment: These aren't going to run with normal javascript, jquery and jqtouch, you have use Closure to run with these.